# Running a JSON graph locally

Tags: noflo

I've been using Flowhub.io to do my development on the nodejs device. Now that the GUI-based design is done, I'm ready to take it offline and run the code via the command line. How would do I do this? I have the JSON file corresponding to the graph I created online, but not sure how to use the noflo nodejs module.

Could someone help me by showing me an example of how to load a graph using the noflo module, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

f you want to run an existing graph, you can use the `--graph` option.

```
noflo-nodejs --graph graphs/MyMainGraph.json
```

If you also want the process to exit when the network stops, you can pass `--batch`.

*PS:* I added this to the [noflo-nodejs README](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-nodejs#starting-an-existing-graph).